# How can i get all calendar and its events from iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, events, calendar

Good Day to you. I have used iCal events in my app. I have add events to iCal and retrieve/delete the events from iCal from my sample iPhone app. Now, i want to show all the calendars what are the calendars user synced in their iPhone(Eg : Google calendar). Then i want to retrieve the events from other calendars except iCal. How can i get all the synced calendars from iPhone? I searched my level best in Google but, can't to get right answer. Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this code is not working. can u give me how to get events and how to clear all events in calendar in iphone

Comment: @ Yuvaraj.M from where you download the ical sample code. please tell me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I thank you all for viewing my question. I got the solution for my question. I just retrieved the calendars from `EKEventStore` and used `EKCalendar`. Here is my code,

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[[EKEventStore alloc] init] autorelease]; 
EKEvent *events = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
NSArray *caleandarsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
caleandarsArray = [[eventStore calendars] retain]; 

 for (EKCalendar *iCalendars in caleandarsArray) 
 {
     NSLog(@"Calendar Title : %@", iCalendars.title);

 }
```

This code working for me. Thanks.

Comment: this code is not working. can u give me how to get events and how to clear all events in calendar in iphone..

Answer (score 4):

The above code is allocating a new array and pointing the reference to a different array. Isn't this a memory leak?

```
NSArray *caleandarsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
caleandarsArray = [[eventStore caleandarsArray] retain];
```

This is more optimal.

```
NSArray *caleandarsArray = [[eventStore caleandarsArray] retain];
```